# Which steps are needed for an Unicode program in C++

Tags: c++

I want to write a C++ program which can support typing Unicode characters in text editors like LibreOffice, MS Office, Notepad, (because I'm a Vietnamese and my mother tongue language includes Unicode characters such as: đ, â, à ế, ẹ, ẻ, ...). That means when I use a text editor like those above or any applications which can support text editing such as Browsers (in address bar or search bar), Chat applications like Yahoo or Skype, ... and when I type a key or a group of keys in keyboard, my C++ program will notice that and convert it into Unicode character and send it back to text editor.

For example, when I type double 'e' key in text editor, C++ program with notice that and make it as 'ê' in text editor. Please tell me steps needed or mechanism to do a such application. I don't know where to start.

Comment: "Tongue" is a little outdated, I'd use "language" instead.

Comment: Can't you use an IME?

Comment: You do need a bit of context understanding. For instance, many games use `WASD`  keys for navigation. `AA` means "go left, twice", not "Á".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood you want to write an IME (input method editor). There are plenty of them available already for Vietnamese, supporting various input methods.

You did not specify the platform. However for both Windows and Linux there are quite a many Vietnamese IMEs available - practically all are open source for Linux, and [Unikey](http://unikey.org/), which to my knowledge is one of the most popular IMEs for Windows, is also an open source program, and thus would provide an easy start for hacking your own favourite options to an IME.

Answer (score 2):

Use a solid library like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/), or if you don't need extra ballast, plain old [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/)

Comment: @MSalters no, it probably will need help with that. I'd suggest Qt with a custom TextEditBox widget which is going to be a pain to write.

Comment: Hey, ICU is old enough for a drivers' license in some areas!
Obligatory response to the obligatory 'ICU is too big' - ICU can be static linked, reconfigured, etc to be much smaller, see docs.

But on topic, ICU doesn't handle GUI of any sort, the only input supported is console input (stdin).    Edit:  QT5 seems to depend on ICU FWIW: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-ICU

Comment: @Steven in my defense, I said use ICU to keep it small, because indeed, Qt provides a lot more than only Unicode support.

Comment: @rubenvb oh my - I read it too quickly, sorry. Usually ICU is the one with ballast! But, I was trying to have fun with the 'old' part.  Should have said: "and if ICU itself is too big..."